# Example of CDocument::ReleaseFile for MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

How can I use `CDocument::ReleaseFile` in MFC?

In the Microsoft Docs there's only the member function, but not an example.

Answer (score 0):

[Create Thumbnail Extractor Objects for Your MFC Document Types](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEA_enIN866IN866&sxsrf=ACYBGNSG_5Ae7bwcb6Extzs1DWALGQT0kA%3A1570193360034&ei=0D-XXcDOAfHYz7sP45KE2A0&q=ReleaseFile%20mfc&oq=ReleaseFile%20mfc&gs_l=psy-ab.3...97364.97571..97851...0.1..0.161.289.0j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.ROeNn39RzH0&ved=0ahUKEwjA9s-L0oLlAhVx7HMBHWMJAdsQ4dUDCAs&uact=5#)

```
 // load content of file, code taken from MFC OnOpenDocument and modified
 CFileException fe;
 CFile* pFile = m_pDoc->GetFile(sFileName,    CFile::modeRead, &fe);
 if (pFile == NULL)
     return FALSE;

 m_pDoc->DeleteContents();
 CArchive loadArchive(pFile, CArchive::load | CArchive::bNoFlushOnDelete);
 loadArchive.m_pDocument = m_pDoc;
 loadArchive.m_bForceFlat = FALSE;
 try
 {
     if (pFile->GetLength() != 0)
         m_pDoc->Serialize(loadArchive);     // load me
     loadArchive.Close();
     m_pDoc->ReleaseFile(pFile, FALSE);
 }
 catch(CException *e)
 {
     //e->ReportError();
     m_pDoc->ReleaseFile(pFile, TRUE);
     m_pDoc->DeleteContents();   // remove failed contents
     e->Delete();
     return FALSE;
 }
 return TRUE;
 //delete pDoc;
```